# Convert BSQ to BIL

Tags: band-interleaved-by-line

I have this set of BSQ files that contain information about meteorological enesembles. I want to import them using a software called `Delft-FEWS`, which only supports import of BIL files. Each file contains 17 bands and 216 time steps. So I have a fourth dimension in the file, which is, so the source of the files told me, not clearly defined by the format. I know, that `Delft-FEWS` can handle BIL files containing meteorological ensemble data but cannot handle BSQ data.

I can open the files using GIS software like `ArcMap` or `GNU R`, extract each time step manually and save it as BIL file. But I am looking for a way to automatically convert those BSQ files to BIL files that takes in account the time dimension, too. Of course I can write a little program that does that but maybe I can save my time and use something that already exists.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the GIS software you are using, and what you have tried. I can't think of any software that doesn't support BIL.

Comment: If you have `gdal` installed, you could give it a first shot with `gdal_translate -of ENVI -co interleave=bil INPUT OUTPUT`. ENVI can transform BSQ to BIL in place, but needs a licence, unfortunately.